# How to groupby and join, and then fillna from adjacent columns

Tags: python, pandas

In [How to groupby multiple columns and aggregate diff on different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143703/how-to-groupby-multiple-columns-and-aggregate-diff-on-different-columns/64144025?noredirect=1#comment113552286_64144025), difference fields for two columns, were created from my data (see code below)

I would like to take this one step farther, and make the value of **cnt_a_diff** and **cnt_b_diff** for only the first row of each grouping equal to the value of **cnt_a** and **cnt_b**.   And I'm trying to find the most straight-forward way of doing that

**Heres the output data I'd like to have:   (only rows 0,3 and 6 would be affected)**

```
        date  county       state  cnt_a  cnt_b  cnt_a_diff  cnt_b_diff
0 2020-06-13  Bergen  New Jersey    308     11       308.0        11.0
1 2020-06-14  Bergen  New Jersey    308     11         0.0         0.0
2 2020-06-15  Bergen  New Jersey    320     15        12.0         4.0
3 2020-06-12   Union  New Jersey    100      3       100.0         3.0
4 2020-06-13   Union  New Jersey    130      4        30.0         1.0
5 2020-06-14   Union  New Jersey    150      5        20.0         1.0
6 2020-06-12   Bronx    New York    200    100       200.0       100.0
7 2020-06-13   Bronx    New York    210    200        10.0       100.0
```

**Here is Trenton's code and output:**

```js
import pandas as pd

# setup the test dataframe
data = {'date': ['2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13'],
        'county': ['Bergen', 'Bergen', 'Bergen', 'Union', 'Union', 'Union', 'Bronx', 'Bronx'],
        'state': ['New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'New York'],
        'cnt_a': [308, 308, 320, 100, 130, 150, 200, 210],
        'cnt_b': [11, 11, 15, 3, 4, 5, 100, 200]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# set the date column to a datetime format
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# sort the values
df = df.sort_values(['state', 'county', 'date'])

# groupby and join back to dataframe df
df = df.join(df.groupby(['state', 'county'])[['cnt_a', 'cnt_b']].diff().fillna(0), rsuffix='_diff')

# display(df)
        date  county       state  cnt_a  cnt_b  cnt_a_diff  cnt_b_diff
0 2020-06-13  Bergen  New Jersey    308     11         0.0         0.0
1 2020-06-14  Bergen  New Jersey    308     11         0.0         0.0
2 2020-06-15  Bergen  New Jersey    320     15        12.0         4.0
3 2020-06-12   Union  New Jersey    100      3         0.0         0.0
4 2020-06-13   Union  New Jersey    130      4        30.0         1.0
5 2020-06-14   Union  New Jersey    150      5        20.0         1.0
6 2020-06-12   Bronx    New York    200    100         0.0         0.0
7 2020-06-13   Bronx    New York    210    200        10.0       100.0
```

**Total code from the updated answer:**

```
# setup the test dataframe
data = {'date': ['2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13'],
        'county': ['Bergen', 'Bergen', 'Bergen', 'Union', 'Union', 'Union', 'Bronx', 'Bronx'],
        'state': ['New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New Jersey', 'New York', 'New York'],
        'cnt_a': [308, 308, 320, 100, 130, 150, 200, 210],
        'cnt_b': [11, 11, 15, 3, 4, 5, 100, 200]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# set the date column to a datetime format
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# sort the values
df = df.sort_values(['state', 'county', 'date'])

# groupby and join back to dataframe df without fillna
df = df.join(df.groupby(['state', 'county'])[['cnt_a', 'cnt_b']].diff(), rsuffix='_diff')

# use fillna with axis=0
df[['cnt_a_diff', 'cnt_b_diff']].fillna(df[['cnt_a', 'cnt_b']], axis=0, inplace=True)

# display(df)
df.head(20)

    date    county  state   cnt_a   cnt_b   cnt_a_diff  cnt_b_diff  cnt_a_diff  cnt_b_diff
0   2020-06-13  Bergen  New Jersey  308     11  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2020-06-14  Bergen  New Jersey  308     11  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   2020-06-15  Bergen  New Jersey  320     15  12.0    4.0     12.0    4.0
3   2020-06-12  Union   New Jersey  100     3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
4   2020-06-13  Union   New Jersey  130     4   30.0    1.0     30.0    1.0
5   2020-06-14  Union   New Jersey  150     5   20.0    1.0     20.0    1.0
6   2020-06-12  Bronx   New York    200     100     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   2020-06-13  Bronx   New York    210     200     10.0    100.0   10.0    100.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Vectorized Solution

- Here is a vectorized approach using [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on the columns, using `axis=1`, after doing the `.join`.

  - `fillna` can accept a `DataFrame` for the `value` parameter.

```py
# groupby and join back to dataframe df without fillna
df = df.join(df.groupby(['state', 'county'])[['cnt_a', 'cnt_b']].diff(), rsuffix='_diff')

# fillna for cnt_a_diff
df.cnt_a_diff = df.cnt_a_diff.fillna(df.cnt_a)

# fillna for cnt_b_diff
df.cnt_b_diff = df.cnt_b_diff.fillna(df.cnt_b)

# display(df)
        date  county       state  cnt_a  cnt_b  cnt_a_diff  cnt_b_diff
0 2020-06-13  Bergen  New Jersey    308     11       308.0        11.0
1 2020-06-14  Bergen  New Jersey    308     11         0.0         0.0
2 2020-06-15  Bergen  New Jersey    320     15        12.0         4.0
3 2020-06-12   Union  New Jersey    100      3       100.0         3.0
4 2020-06-13   Union  New Jersey    130      4        30.0         1.0
5 2020-06-14   Union  New Jersey    150      5        20.0         1.0
6 2020-06-12   Bronx    New York    200    100       200.0       100.0
7 2020-06-13   Bronx    New York    210    200        10.0       100.0
```

### Original Non-Vectorized Solution

- Remove `fillna(0)` from the `groupby`
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), to perform a row by row function, using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign the values from `cnt_a` and `cnt_b`, to `cnt_a_diff` and `cnt_b_diff`, respectively, if `cnt_a_diff` and `cnt_b_diff` is `NaN`.

  - `np.where(x[-2:].isna(), x[:2], x[-2:]`

    - For each row `x` is `[308, 11, nan, nan]`, for example

      - `x[-2:]` is `[nan, nan]`
      - `x[:2]` is `[308, 11]`
- `.iloc[:, -4:]` selects the last 4 columns of the dataframe.

```py
# groupby and join back to dataframe df without fillna
df = df.join(df.groupby(['state', 'county'])[['cnt_a', 'cnt_b']].diff(), rsuffix='_diff')

# use np.where to update the _diff column values, if they are NaN
df[['cnt_a_diff', 'cnt_b_diff']] = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, -4:].apply(lambda x: np.where(x[-2:].isna(), x[:2], x[-2:]), axis=1).to_list(), index=df.index)
```

Comment: Eureka, it worked fine for me that time and look less than 15 seconds at 300k records!   Thank you for the excellent followup!

Comment: @JamesH You're welcome. Glad we could get that ironed out.